# How to identify the target child path of mouse events from CompoundPath in PaperJS?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm adding the 'mousedown' event listener to the CompoundPath (not to it's children). But I need to know on which child the event occured. The 'target' property of the event object is returning the CompoundPath. So, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution mainly depend on your specific use case.
But a generic way to solve this could be to do a hit test at the event point on each of the `CompoundPath` children and deduce which one triggered the event.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.3/S/nVLLbsIwEPyVVS5J1BARJC6p6CW9VqpUbsDBdZbGxXiR7UAllH+vnQekSBzoSlG0m/HMeDbnQLE9BnnwsUPLqyAJOJW+56SMBS40l5jBAhSe4J3ZKi3aUXRe67UCVxyVRZ3DUeAp7RqYwHyaDADNSlGb3I38pImf/cs/Y4nZoxJPj0jQ/kC1Kj15r1OMRiOhSshSo8ph1d88GfxtLmJbIWVBkpyhkDRTXxhevpF6o9rgK50cBx6dVVi8wIXfl9hC1JOnlbBLNDZqkemBhLJx/Bfui0nUNgq7U5ABl4LvsAy7ew6oBlAaHPHP/sc/u8c/NM1NyO3ePPcSf+woTHKLUtalVHg+lw2wPs1rYK2n282upglMsvn0mvl3bazYCs6sIJds2EHDkRH3535qZLuW0AT5atP8Ag==) demonstrating the solution.

```
const circle1 = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center - 50,
    radius: 50
});

const circle2 = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center + 50,
    radius: 50
});

const compoundPath = new CompoundPath({
    children: [circle1, circle2],
    fillColor: 'orange',
    onMouseDown: event => {
        if (circle1.hitTest(event.point)) {
            alert('circle 1 clicked');
        } else if (circle2.hitTest(event.point)) {
            alert('circle 2 clicked');
        }
    }
});
```